# backstretch animation inside element

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

I need a little help with backstretch using. I use backstretch inside of class element because in a slideshow I wanna have fixed buttons. 
The code for backstretch is here:

```
   $(".backstretch").backstretch([
      "/images/1.jpg",
      "/images/2.jpg",
      "/images/3.jpg"
], {
    fade: 950,
    duration: 10000,
});
```

The problem is, that backstretch makes this element very wide, and it cuts from the image.Does anyone knows why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Does your image have background-size property set to something else than 'cover'? 
Otherwise try this in firebug css and see the result.